# CMOS Scaling vs Die Shrink

Tags: cpu, hardware, cpu-architecture

I would like to ask someone if these two terms can be used interchangeably.

The context that I intend to use the above terms for is a paper on Moore's Law. I would like to use the CMOS Scaling publication as a reference because the 1988 date and predictions are useful for my topic. I couldn't find any information comparing the two terms, CMOS Scaling and Die Shrink, directly and so I thought this would be a worthy question to, add...

CMOS scaling, http://ce-publications.et.tudelft.nl/publications/510_why_is_cmos_scaling_coming_to_an_end.pdf

Die Shrink wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_shrink

Die Shrink appears to be more often referenced in video tutorials and in other materials that touched on the different constraints to extending and holding Moore's Law.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to compare the two things CMOS scaling and Die Shrink? Well first off Die Shrink is scaling of transistors in the first place, so essentially Die Shrinking and CMOS scaling are the same thing. They both are the same concept, but just have different names.

Comment: Yeah, comparing for the sake of definition and overlap. I agree, after reading about them separately it seems that the two terms split hairs. I just wanted to make sure that they aren't two different sides to the same coin.

Comment: Seems like the best answer that I could come up with,